# How can I position my percentage in the same line as my progressbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I am trying to achieve UI as shown in the image. However I am having little hard time after trying combinations of positioning now I am clueless. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

I just want to place the percent in the same line as my progress bar.

This is what I have : [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ncudouL3/)

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[**Updated** JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncudouL3/4/)

Give the `span`(the percentage number) and the `progress_type2` percentage `width` and `float:left` position:

```
td span{
   float:right;
   width:20%;
   text-align:center;
}
.progress_type2 {
   width:80%;
   float:left;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `float: left` to the div that contains the progress bar (his class is `progress_type2`) and also giv it a width, for example:

```
.progress_type2 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Aminesrine said, you could use {float: left;} on the progress bar element, but you could also use {display: inline-block;} on both elements or {position: absolute;} on the percentage element.

If you would rather risk the elements overlapping before wrapping into a second line, use {position: absolute; top: 7px; right:0px} and adjust the top/right pixels to fit the design you seek. Remember: whenever you are using absolute positioning, grant the parent container a {position: relative}; in this case, the table cell.

Whatever option you choose, be sure to test compatibility and responsiveness. All three options may have different results.